# Firebase auth- failed to register

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

Hello I want to add in my app option to log in and register account. I use firebase auth. 
My Graddle look like this

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.micha.shoppinglist"
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.8.0'
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'





    // butter knife
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'


    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

    // room
    compile "android.arch.lifecycle:runtime:1.0.0-alpha1"
    compile "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.0.0-alpha1"
    annotationProcessor "android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:1.0.0-alpha1"

    compile "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.0.0-alpha1"
    annotationProcessor "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.0.0-alpha1"

    // stetho
    compile 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho:1.3.1'

    // For OkHttp3
    dependencies {
        compile 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho-okhttp3:1.3.1'
    }
// For OkHttp
    dependencies {
        compile 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho-okhttp:1.3.1'
    }
// For UrlConnection
    dependencies {
        compile 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho-urlconnection:1.3.1'
    }


}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

and my function to register account look like this

```
 mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword("myemail@op.pl", "P@ssw0rd")
        .addOnCompleteListener(MainActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Authentication passed.",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                } else {
                    // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                    Log.d("Error", task.getException().getMessage());
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Authentication failed.",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
```

I enable in firebase console option to log in/ register with email/password and i got this error

> 03-31 23:48:46.481 26065-26065/com.example.micha.shoppinglist D/Error: An internal error has occurred. [ Access Not Configured. Google Identity Toolkit API has not been used in project 781137572465 before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/overview?project=781137572465 then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry. ]

I don't know why, because I don't want to use google login form.
I would be grateful if somebody could help me. :)

Comment: Have you enabled `Identity Toolkit API` in Google Cloud console? And also all required Auth services in Firebase console

Comment: In firebase i enabled only emai/password (first option) in google cloud console i did nothing because i dont want to use google login/register window

Comment: I suggest you to go and use [FirebaseUI](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android), is extremely easy to implement sign in, even I can make it!!!

Comment: @Racu FirebaseUI depends on the same underlying `createUserWithEmailAndPassword ` API to create users. So if that call fails *without* FirebaseUI, it will also fail *with* FirebaseUI.

Comment: did you add the google-services.json to your project?

Comment: no because I don't have method set credential